# Seemingly simple REGEX

Tags: regex

I am using REGEX (c# and JS) to extract blocks of text from a larger document.

The way to identify the start (and name of) a block of text is with this REGEX:

```
(.*)\nGeneral Information:
```

There are multiple blocks in the document, each with different layout and length.

How can I capture the block of data that follows after each initial match (and capture) till the end of the document?

I've tried all the simple stuff like ([.\s\n]*) and other basic constructs but I am not seemingly able to the data successfully after I have discovered each blocks starting point.

I am sure that I am missing something really simple here and I just cant think of it. I havent used REGEX in a few years now and am very rusty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

The Frog

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general pattern you may try:

```
General Information:((?!\r?\nGeneral Information:).)*
```

It matches the beginning of a section, then uses a tempered dot (using a negative lookahead) to consume one character at a time.  That lookahead will fail, stopping the match, when the regex comes across a newline followed by a start of the next section.

### Demo